# Formatting datetime in matplot Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

I am having problems to adjust the datetime in a better way to visualize in my graph. 
Here is my code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
new.plot(title='(Graph)',figsize=(10,7), legend=None)

plt.tick_params(axis="both", which="both", bottom="off", top="off",    
                            labelbottom="on", left="off", right="off", labelleft="on")   
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), frameon=False)
ax = plt.subplot(111)   
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)    
ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(True)    
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)    
ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False)    
ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()    
ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
pp.savefig(bbox_inches='tight')
pp.close()
```

I tried to add this library and in the ax nominations:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try rotating the labels adding the paramenter `labelrotation` https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html:

```
plt.tick_params(axis="both", which="both", bottom="off", top="off",    
                        labelbottom="on", left="off", right="off", 
                        labelleft="on", labelrotation=45)
```

Comment: This does not work raises an error. TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rotation'

Comment: try with `labelrotation`. Maybe it depends from the version

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html

Comment: keyword labelrotation is not recognized; valid keywords are ['size', 'width', 'color', 'tickdir', 'pad', 'labelsize', 'labelcolor', 'zorder', 'gridOn', 'tick1On', 'tick2On', 'label1On', 'label2On', 'length', 'direction', 'left', 'bottom', 'right', 'top', 'labelleft', 'labelbottom', 'labelright', 'labeltop']

Comment: Thats weid, also because you use the keyword `which`, which is not listed. Can you try with `tickdir` ?

Answer (score 0):

I just added the following line and it did it automatically

```
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```